# Running cells with 'Python 3.9.5 64-bit' requires ipykernel installed or requires an update and not able to run the cell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I am getting error Running cells with 'Python 3.9.5 64-bit' requires ipykernel installed or requires an update. in visual studio code if I switch anywhere else from home directory.
For example everything is ok when I run this file from the home directory

Here image:
[image]

Comment: What error do you get after using the command?

Answer (score 1):

Why not install the kernel with the suggested command?

```
conda install -n tf ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall
```

Use the following command to select the kernel for jupyter

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to open the command palette
- search and select **Notebook:Select Notebook Kernel**

  [image]
- select kernel

  [image]